# Pass data from array of hashes to Slack message

Tags: ruby, slack-api, jira-rest-api

I'm working on a slack bot which sends direct message to users from Jira project with assigned to them tasks which left to be done. I'm using [Jira-Ruby gem](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby) to fetch all data from Jira.

According to gem docs I've setup a Jira connection:

```
def project_board(project_key)
  client = JIRA::Client.new(options)
  client.Project.find(project_key)
end
```

And I created a method to fetch only assigned tickets that don't have `done` status

```
def fetch_data
  project = project_board
  project.issues.map do |issue|
    next unless issue.fields.dig('status', 'name') != 'Done' && !issue.fields.dig('assignee', 'name').nil?

    {
      key: issue.key,
      name: issue.fields.dig('assignee', 'name'),
      status: issue.fields.dig('status', 'name')
    }
  end.compact
end
```

Which gave me an array of hashes:

```
=> [{:key=>"48", :name=>"john.john1", :status=>"Waiting for DevOps"},
 {:key=>"46", :name=>"john.john3", :status=>"In Progress"},
 {:key=>"45", :name=>"eric.forman", :status=>"Waiting for DevOps"},
 {:key=>"42", :name=>"john.john3", :status=>"Waiting for DevOps"},
 {:key=>"40", :name=>"john.john3", :status=>"Waiting for DevOps"},
 {:key=>"39", :name=>"eric.forman", :status=>"Waiting for DevOps"}]
```

How to pass these data to the slack message to make it look like below?

`message to john.john1`

```
"Hi john.john1, here is the list of your today tasks:
-------------------------------------------
48 - With status: Waiting for DevOps
link https://company_name.atlassian.net/48
"
```

`message to eric.forman:`

```
"Hi eric.forman, here is the list of your today tasks:
-------------------------------------------
id: 45
status: Waiting for DevOps
link: https://company_name.atlassian.net/45
-------
id: 39
status: Waiting for DevOps
link: https://company_name.atlassian.net/45
"
```

etc.

Comment: You're going to have to do the formatting work, there's really no away around that. You can use simple string interpolation most of the time.

Comment: Thanks @tadman ! Yeah, I know that I should use interpolation at the end but I have no idea how to do this formatting work... no clue in that case, to be honest. I could separate each desired value to a different methods but using `project.issues.each` block inside of each method is not quite efficient if I iterate on hash with <1k keys.

Comment: For example: `"Hi #{name}, here is the list of your tasks: #{task_text}"` where `task_text = tasks.map { |t| "id: #{task.id}\n..." }.join("--------\n") }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that before formatting you change the return value of `fetch_data` to something like:

```
def fetch_data
  # Redacted for brevity ...
  end.compact.group_by { |task| task[:name] }
end
```

this will return a hash like

```
{
 "john.john1"=>[
   {:key=>"48", :name=>"john.john1", :status=>"Waiting for DevOps"}
 ], 
 "john.john3"=>[
   {:key=>"46", :name=>"john.john3", :status=>"In Progress"}, 
   {:key=>"42", :name=>"john.john3", :status=>"Waiting for DevOps"}, 
   {:key=>"40", :name=>"john.john3", :status=>"Waiting for DevOps"}
 ], 
 "eric.forman"=>[
   {:key=>"45", :name=>"eric.forman", :status=>"Waiting for DevOps"},
   {:key=>"39", :name=>"eric.forman", :status=>"Waiting for DevOps"}
 ]
}
```

which should make it much simpler to iterate over every user:

```
fetch_data.each do |user, task_list|
  messages = []
  messages << "Hi #{user}, here is the list of your tasks:"
  messages << "-------------------------------------------"
  task_list.each do |task|
  # format each task line
  end

  method_to_send_to_slack(messagges.join("\n"))
end
```